# search function on parse.com overlays search results on original tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm pretty new at this and having a go using Parse.com as the backend server.  I'm building a database of vegetables, and want to perform a search on the list pulled from parse.com.  I have it all working, except for one annoying thing...

Now, I'm using storyboards and have created a custom cell which includes a PFImage thumbnail view, a label showing the vegetable, and then another label showing the season for the vegetable.

When the viewcontroller is called, the list populates perfectly and lists the vegetables in alphabetical order.  Then I drag the window down to reveal the search bar.  I begin typing in a vegetable name, and as I do so the original table data rows begin disappearing (as they should), but the problem is the original table data sticks around.  So, for instance, I'll type "carrot", and all the rows disappear except the top row which still holds a thumbnail of an artichoke (and the label "Artichoke" as well).  But overlayed on that row is also the word "Carrots", which is another vegetable in the list.  If I tap on it, it properly seques to my detail view controller showing carrots.  So everything is working properly, but I can't figure out how to make it so the search results aren't being written over the top of the original data.

Here's the code portions:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.jpg"]];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //add the search bar
    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, self.searchBar.frame.size.height);
    self.tableView.contentOffset = offset;
    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];
    //done adding search bar
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    /*    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
     query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
     }*/

    [query orderByAscending:@"vegetable"];

    return query;
}

// Override to customize the look of a cell representing an object. The default is to display
// a UITableViewCellStyleDefault style cell with the label being the first key in the object.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"VegetableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // more search stuff

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        cell.backgroundColor = cell.backgroundColor;

    }

    else if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        PFObject *searchedVeggie = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchedVeggie objectForKey:@"vegetable"];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        tableView.rowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight;
    }


    PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"vegetableImageFile"];
    PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"];
    thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
    [thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];

    UILabel *vegetableName = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    vegetableName.text = [object objectForKey:@"vegetable"];

    UILabel *vegetableSeason = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    vegetableSeason.text = [object objectForKey:@"vegetableSeason"];
    return cell;

}
```

Lower in the code is my prepareForSeque code and other search methods.  I know it's a little ugly with repeated code, but I've been trying all sorts of things to fix my issue and wasn't going to get around to cleaning things up until I figured out the issue.  Also, I created a new column on parse.com's data browser called lowerCaseVegetable since the search is case sensitive.  So the search is actually performed on that column, but is displayed using the normal "vegetable" column, which has the vegetable name capitalized.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showVegetableDetail"]) {

        if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
            NSLog(@"Search Display Controller");
            VeggieDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

            PFObject *object = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex: self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
            Vegetables *vegetables = [[Vegetables alloc] init];
            vegetables.vegetable = [object objectForKey:@"vegetable"];
            vegetables.vegetableInfo = [object objectForKey:@"vegetableInfo"];
            vegetables.vegetableImageFile = [object objectForKey:@"vegetableImageFile"];
            vegetables.vegetableSeason = [object objectForKey:@"vegetableSeason"];
            destViewController.vegetables = vegetables;

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Default Display Controller");

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        VeggieDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        Vegetables *vegetables = [[Vegetables alloc] init];
        vegetables.vegetable = [object objectForKey:@"vegetable"];
        vegetables.vegetableInfo = [object objectForKey:@"vegetableInfo"];
        vegetables.vegetableImageFile = [object objectForKey:@"vegetableImageFile"];
        vegetables.vegetableSeason = [object objectForKey:@"vegetableSeason"];
        destViewController.vegetables = vegetables;
        }
    }
}

// other search stuff

-(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"Vegetables"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"lowerCaseVegetable"];
    [query whereKey:@"lowerCaseVegetable" containsString:searchTerm];
    NSArray *results = [query findObjects];
    [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:results];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterResults:searchString];
    return YES;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        return self.objects.count;
    } else {
        return self.searchResults.count;
    }
}

-(void)callbackLoadObjectsFromParse:(NSArray *)result error:(NSError *)error {
    if (!error) {
        [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
        [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:result];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    } else {
//        NSLog(@”Error: %@ %@”, [error userInfo]);
    }
}
```

I have a feeling I'm just making a stupid newbie mistake here, but I've only been at this since May, and specifically fighting this issue the last two weeks.  I figured it was about time to ask for help.

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as correct if I helped you?

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented search in my parse app and I think I see the problem:

In your `filterResults` method try using `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` instead of `findObjects` like this:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error){

         [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:array];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

    }];
```

prepareForSegue:

```
Vegetables *vegetables = [[Vegetables alloc] init];
   vegetables.vegetable = [self.selectedObject objectForKey:@"vegetable"];
   vegetables.vegetableInfo = [self.selectedObject objectForKey:@"vegetableInfo"];
   vegetables.vegetableImageFile = [self.selectedObject objectForKey:@"vegetableImageFile"];
   vegetables.vegetableSeason = [self.selectedObject objectForKey:@"vegetableSeason"];
   destViewController.vegetables = vegetables;
```

Comment: That code did get rid of another issue I was having.  I was getting an error about a long running process during the search function.  I had read about implementing findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock, but hadn't gotten around to it since I was fighting my main issue.I went ahead and tried your code suggestion, and it doubled the search results.  When I typed in carrots, it showed Carrots twice in my search results.  I commented out the first [query whereKeyExists] line, and now it's showing single entries... but still is overlaying the Carrots text over the top of the Artichoke thumbnail.

Comment: @user3745566 hmm interesting. The only other thing I can suggest is to move the thumbnail code in cellForRowAtIndexPath into the if statements for the tableviews. I know it would be in both statements, but just try it ;)

Comment: I moved the thumbnail code, and at least that part is fixed.  Unfortunately, the rest of the field (the original text and season) was still present.  So what I did is called vegetableName.text = nil; and vegetableSeason = nil; in the if/else search statement and now the search results are in a basic white tableview (which is fine) with no more overwriting.  The only problem now is when I search (for carrots) and then tap 'Carrots' when it comes up, it doesn't seque with the image file being displayed in the detail view controller like it did before.  Getting closer, I think, though.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3745566 What I would do is in didSelectRowAtIndexPath save the selected object to a PFObject property of the view controller, call it selectedObject, then in prepareForSegue just use that instead of having to use the if statements there. Let me know if it works!

Comment: I'm not currently skilled enough to attempt to code what you're explaining, but I'll do some reading to try to figure it out.  I at least know how to add the method, so that's no problem.  Although I know how to create the PFObject variable, I don't currently understand how to make it a property of the viewcontroller.

Comment: @user3745566 you would declare the property in the header file.

Comment: I'm still a little fuzzy on Objective-C terminology.  I declared the property in the header file.  I guess what I'm saying is I'm not sure of the code to put in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, or what to change in the prepareForSeque method.  That's what's stumping me at the moment.  Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @user3745566 Okay so in didSelectRowAtIndexPath you would do: self.selectedObject = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; then you would call your segue like you did before. I will update my answer with prepareForSegue code.

Comment: I just tried something new, and have more information.  Since the parse method uses loadInBackground on the thumbnail images, they only load when you scroll down to reveal them in the original data list.  So the images aren't yet loaded when I call the image when the seque is called in the DetailViewController.  I tried searching for items displayed immediately & those images show up in a search when I seque to the DetailViewController.  So it looks like that's what I'm fighting right now.  I also notice my code has a bug somewhere because I'm getting duplicate search results sometimes.

Comment: @user3745566 Ahh I see, maybe try saving them when the view loads so you don't have to load them with each cell. The duplicate results is normal, happens all the time for me too, but I don't know why :( If I helped you otherwise, could you please mark my answer as correct?